# In a relational database, should all columns that will be ordered in a query have an index?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, entity-framework, relational-database

I'm accessing the database (Predominately MS SQL Server, Postgre) through ORM and defining attributes (like whether the field/column should have an index) via code.

I'm thinking that if a column will be ordered via ORDER BY, it should have an index, otherwise full table scan will be required every time (e.g. if you want to get top 5 records ordered by date).

As I'm defining these indexes in code (on Entity Framework POCO entities, as .NET attributes), I can access these metadata at runtime. When displaying the data in a grid, I'm planning to make only those columns sortable (by clicking on column header) that have an index attribute. Is my thinking correct, or maybe there exist some reasonable conditions where sorting can be desirable on non-indexed column, or vice-versa (indexed column sorting would not make much sense?..)

In short, is it good to assume that only those columns should be sortable in UI, that have corresponding index applied at the database level?

Or, to phrase more generic question: Should columns that will be ordered always have some sort of index?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need an index depends on how often you query the ordered sequence compared to how often you make changes that could influence the ordered sequence.

Every time you make changes that influence the ordered sequence your database has to reorder the ordered index. So if you will considerably make more changes than queries then the index will be ordered more often than the result of the ordering will be used.

Furthermore it depends on who is willing to wait for the result: the one who makes changes that requires a re-index, or the one who does the queries.

I wouldn't be surprised if the index is ordered by a separate process after the change has been made. If the query is done while the ordering is not finished, the database will need to first finish enough of the ordering before the query can return.

On the other hand, if a new change is made while the ordering that was needed because of an earlier change was not finished, the database probably will not finish the previous ordering, but start ordering the new situation.

So I guess it is not mandatory to have an ordered index for every query. To order every possible column-combination will be too much work, but if quite often a certain ordering is requested by a process that is waiting for the results, it might be wise to create the ordered index.

Answer (score 0):

`order by` doesn't mandate index on a column but if isn't indexed then it will end up doing a file sort than index sort and thus it's always preferred to have those column indexed if you are intended to use them in `WHERE / JOIN ON / HAVING / ORDER BY`.

You can generate the query execution plan and see the differences between the versions (indexed over non-indexed)

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to @Harald Coppoolse for a thorough answer - there's something else which you should know about sorting on the DB, and that it is preferred to be done at the app level. See item number 2 in the following list: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/7-things-developers-should-know-about-sql-server/